# Finding out the name of a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is it at all possible to find out the name of the theme used by this Wordpress site? https://markforged.com/

I've dug around in the source code, but the css seems minified so I cannot find out much.

If anyone can tell me, they will be my hero!

Comment: they are using there custom theme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used this website before today but it seems to work nicely on the few websites I tested: [WP Theme Detector](http://www.wpthemedetector.com/). It doesn't work on the website you linked though, saying that it isn't a WordPress website. It might be using a security plugin to prevent websites like this getting information.

I checked on [Built With](https://builtwith.com/) and can see that it is actually a WordPress website. There might be some details you can gleam from here hopefully.

Comment: Thanks, I actually think its a mash of WP and another CMS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not a WP site. According to Wappalyzer, it appears to be a combination of HTML5 and the Modernizr JS library.

Regardless of how customised a theme is in WP, or how the CSS/JS is minified, a WP site source wouldn't look the one here. Using a plugin like Hide My WP will stop obvious signs of WP in the source, but it still won't look like this source. Using Firebug, there are no indications of anything WP-related.

If they really are using WP and manage to mask it to this degree, I'd be really interested in how they're doing it.

A lot of themes can be made to look like the one here with a little effort, if you really want the same look.

Comment: It must have elements of a WordPress site as it has the WP admin page.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if another site has been put in the same directory but the WP files haven't been purged. It seems odd they'd go to all that effort to mask it being a WP site and leave the login page in plain sight

Answer (score -1):

I have checked a lot of third-party sites, they responded "This is not a WordPress site", but on a specific site I got an alternative respond that the theme might be too custom.

Comment: It must have elements of a WordPress site as it has the WP admin page.